# Non linear system

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Anyone can help me with this system?

$$(I)\ 2x\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) - 4x\sin(\theta) + 10\sin(\theta) = 0$$

$$(II)\ 10x\cos(\theta) - 2x^2\cos(\theta) + x^2(\cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)) = 0$$

I tried to multiply (I) and (II) by several functions, but I did not come up with anything concrete.

There are two semesters I solved in a list of exercises, but I forgot how I did at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation is $2\sin\theta(x\cos\theta-2x+5)=0$

So, $\sin\theta=0$ or $x=\dfrac5{2-\cos\theta}$.

The second equation is $x[10\cos\theta-2x\cos\theta+x(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)]=0$

If $\sin\theta =0$, then $\cos\theta=\pm1$ and hence $x[\pm(10-2x)+x]=0$. This gives $x=10$ or $x=\dfrac{10}3$.

If $x=\dfrac{5}{2-\cos\theta}$, then $x\ne0$ and hence $10\cos\theta-2x\cos\theta+x(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)=0$.

\begin{align*}
10\cos\theta+\left(\dfrac{5}{2-\cos\theta}\right)(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta-2\cos\theta)&=0\\
10\cos\theta(2-\cos\theta)+5(\cos^2\theta-1+\cos^2\theta-2\cos\theta)&=0\\
\cos\theta&=\frac{1}{2}\\
x&=\frac{5}{2-\dfrac12}\\
x&=\frac{10}{3}
\end{align*}

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot.